# What's the equivalent of continue in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to apply a change to just the data that meets a criteria. The data is stored in an array that looks like this.

[image]

I created each of the circles with this code.

```
const circle = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
      .attr("cx", d => Math.floor((Math.random() * 650) + 1))
      .attr("cy", d => Math.floor((Math.random() * 150) + 1))
      .attr("fill", d => d.color)
      .attr("r", d => d.r);
```

I'm trying to apply a change only to a subset of the circles

```
circle
    .selectAll()
    .transition()
    .delay(5000)
    .duration(5000)
    .attr("cx", d => d.change == 1 ? randomIntFromInterval(1,650) : continue)
    .attr("cy", d => d.change == 1 ? randomIntFromInterval(350,450) : continue)
```

But it's giving me this error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'continue'`

Is there a way to tell D3 to do nothing for values where `d.change == 1`?

---

I want to apply a transition to only a subset of the data. I have a timer function that increments with `d3.timeout`. I want to move the nodes where `change` gets changed to one to a new location on the screen and leave the rest where they are.

```
nodes.forEach(function(o, i) {
    o.timeleft -= 1;
    // reset change
    o.change = 0
    if (o.timeleft == 0 && o.istage < o.stages.length - 1) {
        groups[o.group].cnt -= 1;
        o.istage += 1;
        o.group = o.stages[o.istage].stage;
        o.timeleft = o.stages[o.istage].quarters;
        groups[o.group].cnt += 1;
        o.change = 1
    }
});
```

This did it.  (Edit:please see Gerardo Furtado's answer. this in fact does not work)

```
circle
    .data(nodes.filter(d => d.change == 1))
    .transition()
    .delay(500)
    .duration(500)
    .attr("cx", d => randomIntFromInterval(1, 650))
    .attr("cy", d => randomIntFromInterval(500, 600))
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `continue` here? You should be able to "skip" by not returning anything (which implicitly returns `undefined`). Continue can only be used in a for loop, and this is a callback

Comment: I'm trying to update the location for just a subset of the data. If I give it undefined, then it will set the `cx` and `cy` location to undefined and I don't have that stored in the array.

Comment: If I do `circle.selectAll().data(nodes.filter(d => d.change == 1)).enter()` and then apply the change, will it know that I want to manipulate existing data instead of adding new data? (I guess I'll go find out!)

Comment: This is another classic XY problem: tell us what you **want to do**, not what you **tried**.

Comment: I updated it to include more information.

Comment: Use the filter before the transition, and remove that `selectAll()`, which selects nothing.

Comment: I don't know d3, but if you can get what the value already is, use that instead of `continue`.

Comment: That did the trick! I'll add the code to the question in case someone stumbles upon the same thing. Or if you want to put it as an anwser I'll mark it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, D3 ***is*** JavaScript. Your title makes little sense because the error you're facing is a JavaScript syntax error, it has nothing to do with D3.

Back to the question: in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013497/whats-the-equivalent-to-continue-in-d3#comment98671916_56013497) I was talking about [`transition.filter`](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#transition_filter), not about `selection.filter` and even less about `Array.prototype.filter`, which is the solution you used according to your edited question.

`transition.filter` will...

> For each selected element, selects only the elements that match the specified filter, and returns a transition on the resulting selection.

So, we can use it like this (only the first 5 circles have `change: 1`):

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const data = d3.range(10).map(d=>({change:+(d<5)}));

const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 10)
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cy", (_,i)=>10 + i*12)
  .style("fill", "teal");
  
circles.transition()
 .filter(d=>d.change === 1)
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("cx", 290);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Another (rather ugly) alternative for your ternary operator is using a getter:

```
.attr("cx", (d, i, n) => d.change === 1 ? 290 : d3.select(n[i]).attr("cx"));
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg");

const data = d3.range(10).map(d => ({
  change: +(d < 5)
}));

const circles = svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", 10)
  .attr("r", 5)
  .attr("cy", (_, i) => 10 + i * 12)
  .style("fill", "teal");

circles.transition()
  .duration(1000)
  .attr("cx", (d, i, n) => d.change === 1 ? 290 : d3.select(n[i]).attr("cx"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: Why does it matter the placement for filter? The solution I proposed, as you correctly state, does not work. It caused a double-up effect where circles moved twice. It was almost like if one circle in the group passed, then every circle in that state also had their `cx` and `cy`  affected.